# Accessing response from RequestContextHolder

Tags: grails, httpresponse

Is there a way to access the current response inside a Service? I need this to delete an expired Facebook cookie...

I know how to access current request:

```
RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getRequest()
```

No lack with response though.

Answer (score 1):

A service shouldn't know about http, since it's just a Groovy (or sometimes Java) class that has utility methods. But since you're most likely calling it from a controller which does have access, you can extract information from the request in the web layer and pass it to the service layer for processing.

Comment: Well I don't really believe into "purity over everything else". If I have an alternative where a) I have to pass http data to all the methods on the service layer, even those where it's not obvious, this is required or b) just have FacebookService access the cookie of the currently processed request and extract all the data from there, then I'd actually choose b).

Comment: This is why I'm a big fan of abstracting communications AWAY from the controller to the handlerInterceptor.

The business logic should only handle building and returning the 'resource'; I would say even formatting and security checking can be removed in modern architecture because the communication layer needs to handle that on forwards/redirect & this can also be a shared responsibility of external services (ie proxy, message queue).

By abstracting communications, we are better able to share functionality & data w/ the other architectural services that share the IO flow (ie request/response)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Burt in general, but have situations like @julkiewicz mentioned in the comment above, where you have to access a cookie, and don't want to pass all of the information around (especially if the cookie is not needed at the many intermediate layers). The two options I have found are below (the first is cleaner, but I don't know if `WebUtils` is preferred over `RequestContextHolder`, or possibly the other way around.

```
WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest().request.cookies
```

and

```
RequestContextHolder.requestAttributes.request.request.request.cookies
```

I don't know why there are so many nested `request` objects, but I verified this works for me, in Grails 2.4.2.